# Drools Ruleflow from different drl files

Tags: drools, rules

I'm trying to make a drools flow out of different .drl files in order to have a clear rule flow for my project , however the example in the documentation is very simple and has no indication for this .. 
Does anyone know how it's done ?? (linking Droolsflow to drl files in order to make the knowledge base and execute the rules ? (I added "ruleflow-group" to the rule in the .drl file but didn't know how to link it afterwards ) and if you know any useful links on this matter , I'd be grateful if you share ^^

Comment: Which "example" in which "documentation"? What do mean by "this" in "no indication for this"? - The "Number Guess" example in the Drools reference manual explains all there is to rule flow.

Comment: by "this" I meant linking the Rule flow to different DRL files , in fact , every drl file concerns a package in my project but I'd like to make a Rule flow for the whole project linked to all the DRL files . 
In the example "Number Guess " , the rule flow is linked to only one .drl file

Comment: Did you consider using another `kbuilder.add( ..., ResourceType.DRL );`?